# keyboard controlling function error with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode7

I was trying to create a function in order to put keyboard away by clicking outside of the keyboard or return key within the keyboard, but unfortunately it only worked when I clicked outside of the keyboard, it doesn't work to press the  return key in the keyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var numberEnter: UITextField!


@IBAction func findButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    resultLabel.text = numberEnter.text
}


@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField:UITextField) -> Bool{

textField.resignFirstResponder()

return true

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't set the delegate for your text field you will need to do that. You can set the delegate in Interface Builder or in code. See this StackOverflow answer for an example: [Text Field Should Return, is this correct for ios7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687778/text-field-should-return-is-this-correct-for-ios7)

Comment: But i have done this by the other way as input a code  : self.numberEnter = self . and then .  self.numberEnter.delegate = self .

Comment: That way of setting the delegate works fine. :) If I answered your question could you mark it as accepted so that others know you don't need additional help?